# What SSD can I install in a Macbook Air 11" Early 2015 without affecting its sleep functionality?

Tags: ssd, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

I want to upgrade the 128 GB SSD that comes with my Macbook Air 11" Early 2015 to a higher capacity. I've seen several options from brands such as OWC and Transcend, but I've read that after installing those SSDs the Macbook can't go to sleep properly after closing the lid and has to be restarted.

So is there a compatible SSD that doesn't cause that? Or is the only possibility to use an official Apple SSD part?